# How to get environment variable in gomplate arrays?

Tags: go, go-templates, gomplate

I need to create an array of some Environment variables in gomplate template and print in order to see if environment variables are set properly.

I tried from the docs https://docs.gomplate.ca/syntax/#indexing-arrays-and-maps but there is no mention to declare env variable in an array.

Example,

```
{{ $o := jsonArray `[(getenv "USER")]` }}

{{ range ($o) }}
    {{ . }}
{{ end }}
```

It converts the getenv "USER" into a string and does not get my "USER" environment  variable.

The output it returns is (getenv "USER")

Instead it should return pineapple (which is an example user env variable)

Comment: Try using `printf` to interpolate the env var's value into the json string. E.g. something like this: `(printf "[%s]" (getenv "USER"))`?

Comment: No. It is not working. Still converts as a string

Comment: Not sure what you've tried from my first comment that it didn't work, however if I try in on my machine it works just fine. https://imgur.com/KxVFdod

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you so much it worked :) I was missing some braces. However I cannot include multiline values in this array.

for e.g. 
```
{{ $o := jsonArray (printf "[%s]" (getenv "USER"),
"one") }}
{{ range $o }}
  {{ . }}
{{ end }}
```
The error is unexpected "," in operand.

Comment: `{{ $o := jsonArray (printf "[%s, %s]" (getenv "USER") "one") }}` Arguments to template functions are separated by white space, not commas. And don't forget to provide the [*fmt verb*](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) `%s` for each value you want to pass in to `printf`.

Comment: @mkopriva How can I write this in multiline? My strings are too big to write it in a single line. Looks like this does not support multiline formatting. Can you please tell me if it can be written as multiline values?

Comment: Are your variable's values multiline? E.g. does your `USER` or other variable contain multiple lines? Or is the raw text in your template multiline?

Comment: If a variable's value contains multiple lines and you want to pass that to `jsonArray` you can probably use `replaceAll` or `regexp.Replace` to replace new lines with commas or just empty strings. If you want to use multi-line [template actions](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) then that is only possible by using a raw string. *Except for raw strings, actions may not span newlines, although comments can.* https://imgur.com/Bue9iqy (use `replaceAll` to turn new lines into commas, use `strings.Trim` to remove extra commas).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194013/discussion-between-user3597719-and-mkopriva).